# Change input type of a function

Tags: c++, input, types, matrix-multiplication

I have a simple function in c++ to do matrix multiplication. I have defined the function as follows:

```
void matrix_multiplication(std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix1 , std::valarray<std::valarray<double> > matrix2,
                       std::vector<std::vector<double> > &result)
```

Now in some different part of the code, I again need to call this exact same function but with different input types i.e with vectors. Rather than defining another function like below that does the same job as matrix_multiplication:

```
void matrix_multiplication2(std::vector<double>matrix1 ,std::valarray<double> matrix2,
                           std::vector<std::vector<double> > &result)
```

I would like to ask if it is possible to somehow change the input type in two different calls of a function.

Comment: And how do you propose that would work?

Comment: Every time I see a matrix defined by `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` I die a little inside. How on earth do you get multiplication stable with a jagged edge?

Comment: @Bathsheba they don't :P

Comment: _"I would like to ask if it is possible to somehow change the input type in two different calls of a function."_ Isn't that what template functions are for?

Comment: What is the relationship between the `std::valarray<std::valarray<double> >` parameter in the first signature and the `std::valarray<double>` parameter in the second signature?

Comment: Please don't use `std::valarray<std::valarray<...>>` `valarray` has ancillary classes (primarily `slice`, in this case) to let you address it like a 2D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I would like to ask if it is possible to somehow change the input type in two different calls of a function. "*

You can make that function a template (supposed all of the operations of the parameters will work equally for any container type passed):

```
template<typename Container, typename ValArray>
void matrix_multiplication( Container matrix1
                          , ValArray matrix2
                          , Container &result) {
    // Implementation ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answer (and the others like it) is very good. How is he supposed to write a templated function that interprets `std::valarray<std::valarray<double> >` and `std::valarray<double>` the same way? It seems to me that what he's asking is not really possible the way he's asking it. I imagine he would need to overload the function to convert the parameters into something the original function can use, then pass the conversion into the original function to do the legwork.

Comment: @caps Read that small note in the braces: _"(supposed all of the operations of the parameters will work equally for any container type passed)"_

Comment: Sure, but that is not his actual use case--so how does this answer his question?

Comment: @caps The OP didn't clarify their use case very well, besides _"I again need to call this exact same function but with different input types"_

Comment: Would it not be more correct to point out that the function cannot be exactly the same with those different input types?

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, you have a few options:

1) Overload your method to accept the correct arguments.  This use case is precisely why we have function overloading to begin.

2) Convert your arguments before passing them in to your existing function.  This is kind of ugly and, if it's done several times, could end up looking pretty messy.

3) Actually write (or find) a Matrix library and avoid this problem altogether.  This is my preferred solution, but, without knowing the domain over your problem, may be overkill.

Comment: This answer seems to me better than the accepted answer as far as addressing the OP's actual issues. However, it is not very clear or detailed about how to go about any of the suggestions it proposes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at templates in c++, it allows you to do such things in c++.
You can write a template generic function, then write specialization for each type depending on your needs.

take a look at this tuto :

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use templates:

```
template <typename T>
void matrix_multiplication(std::vector<std::vector<T> > matrix1 , std::valarray<std::valarray<T> > matrix2,
                   std::vector<std::vector<T> > &result)
```

Generic programming FTW! However, you are re-inventing the wheel here...writing a good generic library is HARD, and linear algebra is harder, and not as trivial as you think. I suggest Eigen or Armadillo. I mean, based on your function alone I can guess you have a O(n^3) solution to the multiply, when the most efficient are less than that, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations.